# Visual Studio Code convert indentation on an existing project

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have got a "large" project with ~2000 files. I want to change my indentation on the whole project to tabs (with tab size 2). I already changed the workspace settings with theese:

```
 {
    "editor.insertSpaces": false,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.detectIndentation": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true
}
```

I also bound a shortcut key to the "convert indentation to tabs" command. Is there any way to avoid to call the command and save file after file?